# Linked Lists - disappearing data

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I need some help with this linked lists exercise. The function `listTasks()` is supposed to show all the instances of `struct task`. When I execute the function for the first time, it works as expected, but when I execute it again, it doesn't show the stuff from  `struct action`, even if I execute them one after the other.

```
typedef struct action
{
    char parametre[100];
    char command[100];
    struct action* next;
    struct action* previous;
}* Action;

typedef struct task
{
    char name[100];
    struct task* next;
    struct task* previous;
    Action action;
}* Task;

void listTasks(Task tar, char* name)
{

    if(tar==NULL) printf("There is no task with the name: %s\n",name);
    else
    {
        while(tar!=NULL&&strcmp(tar->name,name)!=0)
        {
            tar = tar->next;
        }
        if(tar!=NULL && strcmp(tar->name,name)==0)
        {
            printf("Task: %s\n",tar->name);
            if(tar->action==NULL) printf("->It doesnt have any action.\n");
            else if(tar->action!=NULL)
            {
                while(tar->action!=NULL)
                {
                    printf("->Command: %s\n->->Parametre: %s\n",tar->action->command,tar->action->parametre);
                    tar->action = tar->action->next;
                }
            }
        }
        else printf("There is no task with the name: %s\n",name);
    }


}

void main()
{
   task a = NULL;
   listTasks(a,"random name");
}
```

Comment: My Portuguese is non-existent. Is there a remote chance this can be posted in English (UK, US, or otherwise) ?

Comment: Edit the question accordingly, please.

Comment: My guess is after first time you run listTasks(), the pointer is now pointing to the end of your linkedlist.

Comment: By doing `tar->action = tar->action->next;` aren't you destroying your data structure? If you just want to print that internal list, use a new local-scope pointer to traverse it, so that changing it doesn't affect the actual data structure

Comment: But im not returning any value to the main function.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the data structure exists in memory, and you're directly changing the data stored in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while(tar->action!=NULL)
{
    printf("->Command: %s\n->->Parametre: %s\n",tar->action->command,tar->action->parametre);
    tar->action = tar->action->next;
}
```

You are destructively changing `tar->action`. Yeah, it works for the first time, but after that, `tar->action` will be `NULL`, that's why the data "disappears".

If you don't want to destroy the actions list, you have to traverse it by using a temporary variable. Something along the lines of:

```
struct action *action = tar->action;
while(action!=NULL)
{
    printf("->Command: %s\n->->Parametre: %s\n",action->command,action->parametre);
    action = action->next;
}
```